# How to make tooltip mobile friendly with CSS

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm having some trouble making my tooltip position center in mobile devices. It gets cut and end up in different places, depending on where the tooltip-icon is.
I wrote "position: center" which is obviously not working.
Please help me. :)

```html
.tooltip {   
position: relative;   
display: inline-block;   
border-bottom: none;   
color: #516A66; 
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {   
visibility: hidden;   
width: 400px !important;   
background-color: #516A66;   
color: #fff;   
text-align: center;   
border-radius: 6px;   
padding: 20px;   
position: absolute;   
z-index: 1;   
top: 100%;   
left: 50%;   
margin-left: -200px;   
opacity: 0;   
transition: opacity 1s; 
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
.tooltip .tooltiptext { 
position: center; 
width: 200px !important;   
}} 

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext { 
visibility: visible;   
opacity: 1; 
}  

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {  
content: " ";
position: absolute;
bottom: 100%;  
left: 50%;
margin-left: -5px;
border-width: 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: transparent transparent #516A66 transparent
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext { 
visibility: visible; 
}
```

Comment: Hi, please provide us with a minimal example so that we can test and help you without implementing the base files ourselves.

Comment: Not sure if this is a minimal example :) But what I mean is: In mobile devices, the tooltip text appears underneath the tooltip icon. Depending on where the tool-tip icon is on the screen (i have plenty of tool-tips), the tool-tip text sometimes get cut. So I'm wondering if there is a css-code that makes the tooltip-text centered, or fixed, in mobile devices and not depending on the tool-tip icon!

 <div class="tooltip"> <img src="*the tool-tip icon*" height="18" width="15" padding="15 px" style="vertical align:bottom">    
<span class="tooltiptext">
*text in tool-tip*
</span> 
</div>

Comment: A good way of asking a question is including everything in the question and preferably adding a link to jsfiddle or the likes. Also editing your original question with the pure HTML would be nice. 

But to answer your question, would a `margin: auto` fix your issue?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new at this! Thank you for your answer. I'm gonna try it right away.